# tell Ansible to elm init

Tags: ansible, elm, ansible-role

I have a ansible role for elm setup, and the last task is `elm init`, to configure initial elm project, but I'm having problem with this task because I need to tell yes when elm prompt me

> Hello! Elm projects always start with an elm.json file. I can create
>   them!
>
> Now you may be wondering, what will be in this file? How do I add Elm
>   files to my project? How do I see it in the browser? How will my code
>   grow? Do I need more directories? What about tests? Etc.
>
> Check out https://elm-lang.org/0.19.0/init for all the answers!
>
> Knowing all that, would you like me to create an elm.json file now?
>   [Y/n]: y

Ansible does not understand this, so how can I tell Ansible to say `Y`?

Ansible task is:

```
- name: setup elm project
  shell: elm init path="{{ project_path }}"
  tags:
    - configuration
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard way to do this in a unix shell is to [pipe](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pipelines.html) [yes](https://linux.die.net/man/1/yes) to the command, which will send it a `y` every time it asks. And since ansible will take any shell command, this should work on any Unix/Linux/macOS machine:

```
shell: yes | elm init path="{{ project_path }}"
```